# Unable to invalidate timer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I am trying to use a timer in my application where I want to start a timer on viewWillAppear and want to stop it in the viewWillDisappear method. I have done following coding:
in .h:
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillAppear:FALSE];
   if(!_timer){
     _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                                              target: self
                                            selector:@selector(reloadInboxMessages)
                                            userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
  }
}

-(void)reloadInboxMessages {
  NSLog(@"reloadInboxMessages");
  [tblvwMessage reloadData];
 }

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillDisappear:FALSE];

   NSLog(@"viewWillDisappear");
   if([_timer isValid]){
       [_timer invalidate];
       _timer = nil;
   }
}
```

I thought it would be simple task to do but I am not sure why it is not working. What is the issue?

Comment: check with NSLog if your code enter in: if([_timer isValid])

Comment: yes it is valid. Code in the block  isValid is being executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working?" Is the timer firing when it should not, or failing to fire when it should, or something else?

Comment: You need to add calls to `[super viewWillAppear]` and `[super viewWillDisappear]` in your methods. Let me know if that fixes the problem :)

Comment: @BlackRider I have tried adding it but it didn't work.. I have updated my code above but sorry about the format it has got disrupted now.

Comment: @RobNapier I mean invalidate is not able to invalidate the timer

Comment: Can you show how you declared the timer?

Comment: @Ilario I have just updated my declaration in the code above: property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you saying that you continue to see the log, "reloadInboxMessages", after you go away from this controller?

Comment: I tested your code (commenting the line "[tblvwMessage reloadData]"
) and worked normally. The timer stopped when the view disappeared and restarted when the view appeared.

Comment: To put a finer point on @rdelmar 's question, are you saying you can NSLog on the invalidate and NSLog on the reload method and that the reload log message appears _after_ the invalidate?

Comment: btw I am using the code in a tab viewcontroller. I hope that is not an issue. The code to invalidate is executed but it doesn't stop the timer. Even when I am on other screen it displays nslog from timer screen.

Comment: replace _timer with timer

Comment: Just use this then it should work  if(_timer){
       [_timer invalidate];
       _timer = nil;
   } try using these lines of code in -(void)reloadInboxMessages

Comment: Something else must be going on that you're not telling us. That code should work fine in one of a tab bar controller's content controllers. If you can post the project somewhere, I'll take a look at it -- I'm guessing that the fix will be simple.

Answer (score 0):

try self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval ...

Answer (score -1):

There are three ways to create a timer:

Use the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: or scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: class method to create the timer and schedule it on the current run loop in the default mode.

Use the timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: or timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: class method to create the timer object without scheduling it on a run loop. (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling the addTimer:forMode: method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)

Allocate the timer and initialize it using the initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: method. (After creating it, you must add the timer to a run loop manually by calling the addTimer:forMode: method of the corresponding NSRunLoop object.)

EDIT:

You are using method which already adds it to mainLoop from - create a timer with second approach and leave manual adding.

You must send invalidate message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.

EDIT:

to invalidate the timer that is passed in the callback, but that won't occur within viewWillDisappear method:. therefore, it doesn't quite apply in this scenario:

- (void)onTimer:(NSTimer *)pTimer
  {
  [pTimer invalidate];
  }

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can certainly invalidate a timer created with the method used by the OP.